# PnP Provisioning Schema - disable comments in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, pnp-provision, comments

Using PnP Provisioning Schema for site structure (lists, CTs, fields, etc). 
Want to disable modern comments via [schema](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/blob/master/ProvisioningSchema-2022-09.md) - referring to property in screenshot below
[image]

How to achieve that via provisioning schema?
 (No, I am not interested in doing it manually or via PowerShell).

Comment: Try setting `DisableCommenting` property to `true` with `<pnp:ListInstance>`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Sorry, nope - schema does not have such property.

Comment: Did you try adding it or just looking at/comparing with schema from the link you shared?

Comment: Tried adding - you get error if you add it `Template is not valid
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The 'DisableCommenting' attribute is not declared.)`

Comment: ok. Maybe a good enhancement request/idea to PnP Provision schema.

Comment: Definitely. I thought maybe I am missing a thing, so reaching out here. :)

Comment: Submitted: https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/issues/611

Answer (score 1):

As already alluded to in the comments for the question, this is not currently possible via the PnP provisioning engine and is therefore not part of the schema. This is likely because the option to disable comments at list level was a recent addition, after major releases to PnP provisioning.

I would recommend making a suggested enhancement to the [PnP Framework GitHub repository](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework), since the provisioning engine is part of that library. The issue you have logged is to the schema, but the schema only represents what the provisioning engine can currently process. The change needs to be made to PnP Framework before the schema can be updated.

Answer (score 1):

As per our discussion in comments section above, disabling comments in SharePoint lists is not yet supported by PnP Provisioning Schema.

I have added new feature/idea request to add support for enabling/disabling comments in SharePoint lists using PnP Provisioning Schema at:

[[FEATURE/Idea] - Allow enabling/disabling comments on individual SharePoint lists by adding support for DisableCommenting in ListInstance](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/issues/862)

---

**Additional Read**:

As this is not yet supported by using PnP Provisioning Schema, you have to do it either manually or using PnP PowerShell or using SharePoint REST API (I know you are not interested in doing it manually or via PowerShell, but these are the only options available currently).

Check these for detailed steps on same:

1. [Enable/Disable the comments for a SharePoint Online/Microsoft List - manually](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/05/23/enable-disable-the-comments-for-a-sharepoint-online-microsoft-list/)
2. [Enable/Disable SharePoint Online List Comments using PnP PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/03/19/enable-disable-sharepoint-online-list-comments-using-pnp-powershell/)
3. [Enable/Disable SharePoint Online List Comments using SharePoint REST API](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/03/19/enable-disable-sharepoint-online-list-comments-using-sharepoint-rest-api/)